# How do I open a custom module ajax form in colorbox popup?

Tags: 8, javascript

How do I open a custom module AJAX form in colorbox popup using button click?

Answer (score 1):

If you output your form hidden in the html, you can pop it up with [colorbox_inline](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_inline).

If your form lives in a menu callback and has a path, you can put a rendered link to your page everywhere and it will open modal with [colorbox_load](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_load) - see also [ng_lightbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/ng_lightbox), if you put your path in it's config.